# Looking for resources about visualizing in mathematics

Tags: textbooks, visual-proof

I have learned some useful tools/books to visualize some MATH concepts:

- [Visual Group Theory (MAA Problem Book Series) 1st Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/088385757X). The paired website with this book is [GroupExplorer](https://nathancarter.github.io/group-explorer/index.html)
- [Visual Complex Analysis New Ed Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0198534469)
- $\cdots$

---

I'm Looking for more useful resources about visualization in math. Any supplementation would be appreciated.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1299876/textbooks-for-visual-learners, which recommends plenty of resources, including both books you cited.

Comment: What level of math @138Aspen?